# CodeceptJS: Semantical check for assigned tags

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, codeceptjs

we are currently trying to implement codeceptjs e2e test suites for our application.

We are using some tags at the tests to identify tests which should only run under specific circumstances (for instance only on some country channels with specific features enabled).

It is actually required for a test to have at least one tag of a specific category to run successfully. Therefore we want to force our developers to implement tags. If they don't the build process should fail.

We struggle to find a reliable way to do this so far. We think the safest way would be something like a dry-run mode which either allows us to loop all scenario objects in javascript and check the tags or at least print the scenario names so we can grep on them. Unfortunatley we did not find a way to do this from the codecept docs.

Can someone give us a hint how we could achieve what we are looking for?

Thank you very much